# iphone sdk transparent subview background

Tags: iphone, uiview, transparent

I have a main view with a picture on it.

I am trying to add a subview with `[self.view addSubview:view2];` but I want the view2 background to be transparent. Have tried **opaque=no** and background color to clearcolor and also tried to subclass a uiview and rewrite the drawrect with:

```
#import "TransparentView.h"


@implementation TransparentView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        self.opaque=NO;
        self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing=YES;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(context, rect);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
}


@end
```

But still doesn't display the background of the subview transparent... any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0];
view.opaque = NO;
```

Answer (score 4):

Is the view being loaded from a nib file? If so, the `-initWithFrame:` won't be called; `-initWithCoder:` will be called instead. A better place to do this initialization might be in `-viewDidLoad`. But setting the background color to `[UIColor clearColor]` should definitely do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Try coloring the subview's background with a 0.0 for Alpha.  That should make it completely transparent.

Something like this:

```
UIColor *myUIColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1.0 green: 1.0 blue: 1.0 alpha:0.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

In the function

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

try to update

```
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
```

to

```
  const CGFloat BACKGROUND_OPACITY = 0.85; //Note: update this value to what you need 
  CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 1, 1, BACKGROUND_OPACITY); // You can change 1,1,1 to the needed values
```

This link might help you
http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html

Answer (score 0):

I've had some cases where `... addSubview:clearView]` seemed to reset the background color of `clearView` (*WTF!*) to something not clear. I added a

```
[clearView setBackgroundColor:nil];
```

somewhere after that and it seemed to help.